# What is the nature of a Release assembly that is published as a Debug web API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-debugging

The toolbar lets you set a configuration value that can be either Debug or Release.

[image: toolbar]

The publish page for a web API has a configuration value that can be either Debug or Release.

[image: publish]

What is its relationship to the assembly build types that are also known as Debug and Release in the toolbar? These configuration values can be set independently. This raises the question, what is the nature of a Release assembly that is published as a Debug web API.

Details: C#, CSharp, cSharp, ASP.NET Core, .NET Core, Visual Studio Community 2019, Windows 10, Azure

Comment: _What is its relationship to the assembly build types that are also known as Debug and Release_ - what makes you think they would be different? Sometimes you want to publish a Debug build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The publish setting and the toolbar setting appear to be independent.

If the publish setting is set to "Release" when "Release" has not been previously built, it will get built and it probably does not matter whether the toolbar setting agrees.

If the publish setting is set to "Debug" when "Debug" has not been previously built, it will get built and it probably does not matter whether the toolbar setting agrees.

If you enter the dialog to set the publish type, it will automatically build the "Debug" version. It might build the "Debug" version needlessly because you can enter the dialog and leave dialog without ever having set it to "Debug". That is it is initially "Release" and remains "Release" when you hit save. Thus the "Debug" version is needlessly created.

If you enter the dialog to set the publish type to "Release", it will not automatically build the "Release" version until after you hit "save" on the dialog and then hit "publish".

From the behavior I observed, I have no reason to believe "publish debug" creates a different assembly than the one created by "toolbar debug F6-build".

From the behavior I observed, I have no reason to believe "publish release" creates a different assembly than the one created by "toolbar release F6-build".

In the absence of information that the assemblies created differently are actually a different kind of assembly, it may be that having 2 independent settings is redundant. I welcome information as to why there seems to be redundant configuration tools.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could mark your own answer so that it will help other community members handle and search similar issues:) Thanks.